# Windows 7 can see all physical memory but is not using it and page faulting rapidly

Tags: windows-7, memory, crash

I built a machine a couple years ago that has been running well until two days ago (of course, as soon as I got my hands on some work).  The machine has 3x2gb ram in a Gigabyte triple channel board and a Radeon 5700 series graphics card.  As of two days ago, I can boot up and use the machine, but after a while a single app will lock up and gradually all the running apps on the machine will follow suit until it crashes.

Through trying to debug this, I have noticed that I am only every getting up to 30% physical memory, but any active apps I have are page faulting really fast (Chrome is making C~3000~10000/sec, Skype will make ~2000~5000/sec, Catalyst Control Center is make ~2000~4000/sec).

I cleaned out the case and slots with compressed air, ran memory checks, re-installed the graphics driver(I wondered if it had to do with apps that had visual components), and Googled everything I can think of.  What am I missing?

Comment: Is this running Win7 32 bit or 64 bit?  Use this at the command line: wmic os get osarchitecture

Comment: Have you tried removing 1 stick of RAM, booting up, and seeing what the results are (rotating through which one is removed).  I realize this is triple channel, and you'll loose some speed, we're just testing for faulty sticks of memory (I don't ALWAYS trust mem checkers).  This just proves they are right...

Comment: This is 64 bit and I already tried booting up with each stick of RAM individually.  I was actually curious if it could be the memory on the graphics card, but I have no idea if that would show page faults or how you would even test that memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot about this question for a while, but I did manage to solve it.  The firmware on my SSD was out of date, and somehow updating that fixed the problem.

Comment: Very strange one as you wouldn't expect a `paging fault` to coincide with SSD... More along the lines of memory timings!